# Unable to save spark dataframe in phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, apache-phoenix

I am writing below code to save spark dataframe to phonenix:

phoenix_df.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(Map("table"->"TEST","zkUrl"->"defabc10d")).save()

using spark 1.6.0.

However, job is failing with below error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.setValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor

Please provide some solution is anybody faced same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Phoenix connector was built against a specific version of the HBase client (e.g. V1.3), but the HBase client bundled in CDH is a different version (V1.2) and there are breaking API changes.

1. Find out which HBase client is required by your Phoenix connector
2. Download that client from the [HortonWorks repo](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/hbase/)
3. Add these custom JARs to your driver/executors CLASSPATH, just like you did with the Phoenix connector (e.g. `--jars`)
4. Make sure that your custom JARs override the default Cloudera HBase client with `--conf spark.yarn.user.classpath.first=true`

Comment: Hello Samson, Thanks for help .